# How to save data to a text file?

Tags: vb.net

Basically, I have this program, where you click a link and it opens it. But it doesn't save all the links I put in. There is a name list and link list. You can add links and names with the buttons, and then open link with 'watch'. I was primarily going to use this for youtubers and streamers. Here is the code.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim NamePath As String = ("C:\Favoriter\NameList.txt\")
        Dim nsr As StreamReader
        nsr = New StreamReader(NamePath)
        Do Until nsr.EndOfStream
            lstName.Items.Add(nsr.ReadLine)
        Loop
        nsr.Close()

        Dim URLPath As String = ("C:\Favoriter\URLList.txt\")
        Dim usr As StreamReader
        usr = New StreamReader(URLPath)
        Do Until usr.EndOfStream
            lstURL.Items.Add(usr.ReadLine)
        Loop
        usr.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim NamePath As String = ("C:\Favoriter\NameList.txt\")
        Dim nsw As StreamWriter
        nsw = File.CreateText(NamePath)
        Dim NameItems As String
        Do Until lstName.Items.Count.Equals(0)
            NameItems = lstName.Items.Item(0)
            lstName.Items.RemoveAt(0)
            nsw.WriteLine(NameItems)
        Loop
        nsw.Flush()
        nsw.Close()

        Dim URLPath As String = ("C:\Favoriter\URLList.txt\")
        Dim usw As StreamWriter
        usw = File.CreateText(URLPath)
        Dim URLItems As String
        Do Until lstURL.Items.Count.Equals(0)
            URLItems = lstURL.Items.Item(0)
            lstURL.Items.RemoveAt(0)
            usw.WriteLine(URLItems)
        Loop
        usw.Flush()
        usw.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub lblTitle_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTitle.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstName.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstURL_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstURL.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtName.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtURL_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtURL.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        lstName.Items.Add(txtName.Text)
        lstURL.Items.Add(txtURL.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnWatch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnWatch.Click

        If lstURL.SelectedItem = True Then
            Process.Start(lstURL.SelectedItem)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub lblName_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblName.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub lblURL_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblURL.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: your question is not very clear...what exactly is not working as expected?  is there an error?  we arent mindreaders

Comment: Well, in the program, there are 2 textboxes in one box you type the name, the other one you type the url. It saves the name to a listbox and urls in the other. Now what I want it to do is save the urls and names to a txt file after you close the program, then load them up when you open it back up. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You should start by using a file path rather than a folder path.  Do file paths usually end with a "\"?  You might then explain to us EXACTLY what happens when you run that code and how that differs from what you expect.  DO NOT make use guess.  Give us ALL the relevant information.  Also, don't give us irrelevant information, e.g. including empty event handlers in the code you post serves no useful purpose and just makes it harder for us.

Answer (score 0):

As first look i see you are using `File.CreateText(Path)`, this function will overwrite the old file what ever it has data , so everytime after you write your data you delete them by overwriting, you can use

```
if File.Exists(Path) then
File.Open(Path)
else
File.CreateText(Path)
End If
```

like this you will not overwrite each time you write the text .